# Display Arabic text as separate characters (instead of cursive script) using CSS

Tags: css, fonts, arabic, right-to-left

To display license plates in Arabic, I wish to have each letter displayed without joining adjacent characters.

Is it possible to display Arabic text as separate characters, without the cursive script?

Comment: Unless you're doing it for a really good reason, please don't do it. I'm a native Arabic speaker and only see separate Arabic letters in: a) buggy OS and programs like Android early versions and Adobe Flash b) Elementary school for learning. Please please please don't do it, **it is annoying it makes the text unreadable**!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are unique isolated Arabic UTF-8 characters just for this type of purpose.

It's all explained in [this Wikipedia page.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script_in_Unicode)

(sorry, it pasted in as a bit of a mess)

A demonstration for the basic alphabet used in Modern Standard Arabic:

General
Unicode Contextual forms    Name
Isolated    End Middle  Beginning
0623
أ‎  FE83
أ‎  FE84
ـأ‎         ʾalif
0628
ب‎  FE8F
ﺏ‎  FE90
ـب‎ FE92
ـبـ‎    FE91
بـ‎ bāʾ
062A
ت‎  FE95
ﺕ‎  FE96
ـت‎ FE98
ـتـ‎    FE97
تـ‎ tāʾ
062B
ث‎  FE99
ﺙ‎  FE9A
ـث‎ FE9C
ـثـ‎    FE9B
ثـ‎ ṯāʾ
062C
ج‎  FE9D
ﺝ‎  FE9E
ـج‎ FEA0
ـجـ‎    FE9F
جـ‎ ǧīm
062D
ح‎  FEA1
ﺡ‎  FEA2
ـح‎ FEA4
ـحـ‎    FEA3
حـ‎ ḥāʾ
062E
خ‎  FEA5
ﺥ‎  FEA6
ـخ‎ FEA8
ـخـ‎    FEA7
خـ‎ ḫāʾ
062F
د‎  FEA9
ﺩ‎  FEAA
ـد‎         dāl
0630
ذ‎  FEAB
ﺫ‎  FEAC
ـذ‎         ḏāl
0631
ر‎  FEAD
ﺭ‎  FEAE
ـر‎         rāʾ
0632
ز‎  FEAF
ﺯ‎  FEB0
ـز‎         zayn/zāy
0633
س‎  FEB1
ﺱ‎  FEB2
ـس‎ FEB4
ـسـ‎    FEB3
سـ‎ sīn
0634
ش‎  FEB5
ﺵ‎  FEB6
ـش‎ FEB8
ـشـ‎    FEB7
شـ‎ šīn
0635
ص‎  FEB9
ﺹ‎  FEBA
ـص‎ FEBC
ـصـ‎    FEBB
صـ‎ ṣād
0636
ض‎  FEBD
ﺽ‎  FEBE
ـض‎ FEC0
ـضـ‎    FEBF
ضـ‎ ḍād
0637
ط‎  FEC1
ﻁ‎  FEC2
ـط‎ FEC4
ـطـ‎    FEC3
طـ‎ ṭāʾ
0638
ظ‎  FEC5
ﻅ‎  FEC6
ـظ‎ FEC8
ـظـ‎    FEC7
ظـ‎ ẓāʾ
0639
ع‎  FEC9
ﻉ‎  FECA
ـع‎ FECC
ـعـ‎    FECB
عـ‎ ʿayn
063A
غ‎  FECD
ﻍ‎  FECE
ـغ‎ FED0
ـغـ‎    FECF
غـ‎ ġayn
0641
ف‎  FED1
ف‎  FED2
ـف‎ FED4
ـفـ‎    FED3
فـ‎ fāʾ
0642
ق‎  FED5
ﻕ‎  FED6
ـق‎ FED8
ـقـ‎    FED7
قـ‎ qāf
0643
ك‎  FED9
ﻙ‎  FEDA
ـك‎ FEDC
ـكـ‎    FEDB
كـ‎ kāf
0644
ل‎  FEDD
ﻝ‎  FEDE
ـل‎ FEE0
ـلـ‎    FEDF
لـ‎ lām
0645
م‎  FEE1
ﻡ‎  FEE2
ـم‎ FEE4
ـمـ‎    FEE3
مـ‎ mīm
0646
ن‎  FEE5
ن‎  FEE6
ـن‎ FEE8
ـنـ‎    FEE7
نـ‎ nūn
0647
ﻫ‎  FEE9
ﻩ‎  FEEA
ـه‎ FEEC
ـهـ‎    FEEB
هـ‎ hāʾ
0648
و‎  FEED
ﻭ‎  FEEE
ـو‎         wāw
064A
ي‎  FEF1
ﻱ‎  FEF2
ـي‎ FEF4
ـيـ‎    FEF3
يـ‎ yāʾ
0622
آ‎  FE81
ﺁ‎  FE82
ـآ‎         ʾalif maddah
0629
ة‎  FE93
ﺓ‎  FE94
ـة‎ —   —   Tāʾ marbūṭah
0649
ى‎  FEEF
ﻯ‎  FEF0
ـى‎ —   —   ʾalif maqṣūrah
[edit]

Comment: Thanks! I also discovered that it's possible to use a zero-width-non-joiner character (eg, "&zwnj;" in HTML) between each Arabic character.

The use of Isolated characters as described in your answer is the best solution.

Comment: ...and I don't even know Arabic. I built a multilingual site that used it once. Ah, the stuff that accumulates in the brain-pile.